# Hide/Show a section in a Page based on the picklist

Tags: picklist

Is that possible without creating VF page to hide/show certain fields in the page?

So, I have custom object that in it I have picklist with items:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

so based on the pick from picklist you show the user fields

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: I'm almost certain (but not 100%) you'll need to make a VF page to do this. If you want to try and post what you come up with, people here will be more than happy to help you along.

Comment: Using workflows to set different record types depending on picklist values will an option without using a VF page.

Comment: Do you have S-Control available?

Comment: I do not know what is S-Control is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible without visualforce page. Only thing you can do without visualforce page is keep the fields always and validate using validation rule that the fields has value when particular value is selected in picklist.